# Registered user log in for the first time using Facebook - Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth

I am following Ryan's instruction on Omniauth [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?autoplay=true).

However, there is a scenario that Ryan didn't cover:
User already have an account with us, but they signin with Facebook/Linkedin for the first time. In this case, I would like the user to sign-in using traditional sign-in (via Devise), and if he succeeds, create a new Authenication object for future logins.

In particular, when registered user clicks "Signin with Facebook" for the first time, I'll get a hash from callback that contains his Facebook account information. But I don't want to create an authentication for him yet. Instead, I will redirect him to my Devise sign-in page, allowing him to put username and password in. If he signs in successfully, I would like to create a new Authentication object from the information I got from Facebook callback.

What would be a good way to store Facebook hash temporarily, until user logs in successfully?

Thank you.

Below is the code from AuthenticationController.rb that Ryan created, which did not handle the situation I just mentioned:

```
  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
if authentication
  flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
elsif current_user
  current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
  flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
  redirect_to authentications_url
else
  user = User.new
  user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
  if user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
    sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
  else
    session[:omniauth] = omniauth
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this, could you just check to see if there is another user with the same email when they register with facebook? If so, add facebook as a second method of authentication, and if not, create a new account.